# Setting a default filetype for Save As dialog when someone tries to save as the file

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I am sharing a `.xltm` file to my users because my file has macros, and in order to run them one must save-as the file with type `.xlsm`, as the standard filetype doesn't allow macros to run. A lot of my users forget to change the filetype when saving-as the file (by going to File >> Save As), which they need to change from `xls` to `xlsm` type so my macros work in the new workbook.

The default save-as dialog opens with the filetype set to Excel Workbook.

[image]

Can I make it open with the file type set to Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook by default?

[image]

I found out about this code which runs when save is executed -

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    'add some code here which sets the filetype for excel's save-as dialog to macro one
    'and then opens the saveas dialog with the macro filetype
End Sub
```

Is this possible to do? Kindly advice... Thanks! :)

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4416-excel-force-save-as-macro-enabled.html

Comment: If you want to change the Excel setting, you could use `Application.DefaultSaveFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`. To change it manually, e.g. in Office 2019, this setting is the first under `Options>Save` i.e. a combo box with the various file formats.